# Is there a way to make the taskbar box for date and time bigger on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, taskbar

So I recently changed my default font on my laptop and now my date and time are kind of squished and a little hard to read (see image). Is there a way to fix this? I tried making the taskbar bigger by dragging it, but that didn't solve the problem. Any advice would be great, thanks!

[image: taskbar date and time box issue]

Update: I don't know what happened but it fixed itself... [image]

Comment: Increase the taskbar height - just drag the top. If it's in the way of the Desktop, set it to auto-hide.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the standard clock in the tray with a third party app which gives you the control over font size you want, and perhaps more. 
 https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-tray-clock-replacement.htm and https://alternativeto.net/software/tclockex/ list free replacements for the clock, such as [DigitalClock4](https://sourceforge.net/p/digitalclock4/wiki/Home/), [DSclock](https://alternativeto.net/software/ds-clock/), [FreeDesktopClock](https://alternativeto.net/software/free-desktop-clock/), [LClock](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/lclock.htm-0), [TClock EX](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tclockex.htm-0), [TClock Light](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tclock-light.htm), [TClockRedux](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/blob/master/README.md), and [Timekeeper](https://12noon.com/?page_id=178).

Comment: This more or less solves the problem, but not quite what I was looking for. If no one else knows a way to fix the issue though, I'll mark this as the answer!